# Write all running processes to a text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

The purpose of this code is to get a list of all used executables from a specific folder. After a month we will delete any exe's not on this list.

I currently get the correct results using this:

```
while ($true) {
    foreach ($process in Get-Process | where {$_.Path -imatch 'ksv'} | select -Unique) {
        $dir = $process | Get-ChildItem;
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Path' = $process.Path;
        } | Out-String | Add-Content -LiteralPath Z:\processList.txt 
     }
     Get-Content Z:\processList.txt | sort | Get-Unique > Z:\uniqueprocesslist.txt
 }
```

I'm going to get rid of the `while` loop as this will be eventually running as a service.

The problem with this is that it creates a huge list in processlist.txt that I would like to eliminate to save space.

I tried to come up with a better solution that scans the text file to see if the path is written already before adding the new process path. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but nothing is ever written to the text file

```
while ($true) {
    foreach ($process in Get-Process | where {$_.Path -imatch 'ksv'} | select -Unique) {
        $dir = $process | Get-ChildItem;
        $progPath = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            'Path' = $process.Path
        }
        $file = Get-Content "Z:\processList.txt"
        $containsLine = $file | %{$_ -match $progPath}
        if ($containsLine -contains $false) {
            Add-Content -LiteralPath Z:\processList.txt
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to build a "recently used" list of executables in a specific directory in a file, and update that (unique) list with each run of your script.

Something like this should do that:

```
$listfile = 'Z:\processlist.txt'

# Build a dictionary from known paths, so that we can check for already known
# paths with an index lookup instead of a linear search over an array.
$list = @{}
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $listfile) {
    Get-Content $listfile | ForEach-Object {
        $list[$_] = $true
    }
}

# List processes, expand their path, then check if the path contains the
# string "ksv" and isn't already known. Append the results to the list file.
Get-Process |
    Select-Object -Expand Path |
    Sort-Object -Unique |
    Where-Object {$_ -like '*ksv*' -and -not $list.ContainsKey($_)} |
    Add-Content $listfile
```

Hashtable lookup and wildcard match are used for performance reasons, because they're significantly faster than linear searches in arrays and regular expression matches.

Comment: This get's the processes correctly but if it's always running it adds duplicates

Comment: @wprime `Select-Object -Expand -Unique` didn't enforce uniqueness of the processes before the filter. Fixed.

Comment: I tried encompassing this in a while loop since it would be an always running process to catch any program that is ran. I'm still getting duplicate values

Comment: @wprime My bad. `ContainsKey` is a method, not an array, so it must be `$list.ContainsKe(...)`, not `$list.ContainsKey[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($true) {
    $file = Get-Content "Z:\processList.txt"
    $KSVPaths = Get-Process | 
                      Where-Object {$_.Path -imatch 'ksv'} |
                        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path |
                          Select-Object -Unique
    ForEach ($KSVPath in $KSVPaths) {
         if ($KSVPath -notin $file) {
             Add-Content -Path $file -Value $KSVPath
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws an error saying it can't add-content path because path is an empty string.

Comment: oh this might be because Z:\processlist.txt is not visible from powershell.  there are a couple of ways around this.  1) write to C:\processlist.txt on each server and then view the files through other powershell commands 2) use Invoke-Command to run the code from your computer to all the remote servers 3) include code in your script to connect to the Z drive